# Appengine + Maven + Spring + Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine, maven

I want to use maven and spring with appengine, but I can't...

I was able to configure maven with appengine (and spring with appengine, but without maven), but when I add spring dependencies and I try to run it I have the following error:

WARNING: Could not instantiate listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
[...]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter

how I can solve this problem?

I read tons of information but it seems out to date...

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you put more info into your question, but I would say to take a look at the spring artifacts here in maven central : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.springframework and try to choose all a single version that works for you.  I think they are on 3.2.2.RELEASE

Sorry I can't be of more help, but since the springframework docs are a bit outdated for maven support these days (http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework), it can be easy to get a mishmash of versions which cause issues with resolving dependencies.

Try also only declaring the minimum set of dependencies you can, and "mvn dependency:tree" can also clue you into where you might be bringing in duplicate dependencies, which can cause this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

For maven dependancies please have a look at:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework

Make sure you have spring-web dependancy declared.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Please read the appengine spring optimization guide, can save you some hassle later on:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization